# "C stack usage [high number] is too close to the limit" after running catboost multiple times

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, catboost

I have a model in RStudio witch runs different gradient boosting libraries (lgbm, xgboost, catboost). It selects a dataset, builds a model, predicts, and repeats for a different dataset. With xgb or lightgbm I have no issues, with catboost, after several model runs (several thousands) it interrupts and tells me "C stack usage  [high number] is too close to the limit". The [high number] is different every time, but equivalent to several 100 GB storage. Normally, one model run consumes less than 1 GB RAM.
However, after this error message, Rstudio is responding, but not do another catboost call. After restarting Rstudio, the model runs again, but just for several dozen times, then interrupts with the same error message but with another [high number].
After rebooting the machine, it runs several thousands again, next time dozens and so on.
Unfortunately, it is no reproducible, sometimes it runs 10 times, sometimes 100.
For troubleshooting I tried the following, but neither worked:

-changes nvidia driver 440 to 435.

-update to the latest catboost version.

-changed all the catboost learning parameters.

-run detached() and library() for catboost, everytime I trained a model.

Any help appreciated!